# How to add a list of CIDs to an IPFS node

Tags: ipfs, filecoin

I have a list of CIDs (4,000 of them) that I uploaded to nft.storage and now I wish to import them to my own IPFS node. What is the easiest way to do this in bulk? I checked the `ipfs add` command but seems like I can only add one file (not CID) at a time.

Answer (score 1):

You can add multiple CIDs to your node simply by pinning them to your node. To quote [the Kubo docs](https://docs.ipfs.io/reference/cli/#ipfs-pin-add):

```
USAGE
  ipfs pin add <ipfs-path>... - Pin objects to local storage.

SYNOPSIS
  ipfs pin add [--recursive=false] [--progress] [--] <ipfs-path>...

ARGUMENTS

  <ipfs-path>... - Path to object(s) to be pinned.

OPTIONS

  -r, --recursive  bool - Recursively pin the object linked to by the specified
                          object(s). Default: true.
  --progress       bool - Show progress.

DESCRIPTION

  Stores an IPFS object(s) from a given path locally to disk.
```

For example:

```
ipfs pin add QmNsXkTWPv9uNHJGwc4DHM285cipEbDNwoeHiihYsckanu QmQ2KWk5mY4LToqyMoebwMzKLavCBDAyo9B7aZTkeBMy1w
```

Comment: Example please not just cp docs. Especially interested if the IPFS Desktop client can insert a CID list. CL needed for that?

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate your efforts. Now you only need to have "a script" to plot those 4,000 CIDs to add them?